# How to have a wix bundle with prerequisite download and one with prerequisite compressed but be equivalent bundles?

Tags: wix

I want to have two equivalent bundles: one that has the .net framework included (as wix calls it, compressed), and one that will download it. I'm currently creating the two bundles from a single bundle file by using an `<?ifdef?>` that I pass on the command line. Everything works fine except during install, the bundles don't fail to install if the other one is already installed. The log shows that it detected the related bundle, but WixBundleInstalled is set to 0. Is there a way to do this so that the bundles can't be installed on top of each other?

Here is the bundle file:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:netfx='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension'
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <?include Settings.wxi ?>
  <Bundle UpgradeCode="GUID" Version='$(var.ProductVersion)'
          Name="MyTune" DisableModify="yes"
          IconSourceFile="../icon_gear.ico" Manufacturer='GearHead Software, LLC' UpdateUrl='$(var.UpdateUrl)'>
    <OptionalUpdateRegistration/>
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLargeLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="..\EULA.rtf" SuppressOptionsUI="yes" ShowVersion="yes" ThemeFile="RtfLargeTheme.xml"
                                              LaunchTarget="[ProgramFilesFolder]\GearHead Software\MyTune\MyTune.exe"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <Chain>
      <?ifdef IncludeDotNet ?>
        <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40RedistCompressed"/>
      <?else?>
        <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Redist"/>
      <?endif?>
      <MsiPackage Id="MyTune" SourceFile="MyTune.msi" DisplayName="MyTune" />
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>

  <Fragment>
    <util:RegistrySearchRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40"/>

    <PackageGroup Id="NetFx40RedistCompressed">
      <ExePackage
          InstallCommand="/q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot;"
          RepairCommand="/q /norestart /repair /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot;"
          UninstallCommand="/uninstall /q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot;"
          PerMachine="yes"
          DetectCondition="NETFRAMEWORK40"
          Id="NetFx40RedistCompressed"
          Vital="yes"
          Permanent="yes"
          Protocol="netfx4"
          Compressed="yes"
          SourceFile="dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe">
      </ExePackage>
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Here is the log file from installing the bundle with .net included while the bundle without .net is already installed:

```
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:19]i001: Burn v3.8.1128.0, Windows v5.1 (Build 2600: Service Pack 3), path: C:\MyTune1440_setup.exe, cmdline: ''
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:19]i000: Initializing string variable 'LaunchTarget' to value '[ProgramFilesFolder]\GearHead Software\MyTune\MyTune.exe'
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\MyTune_20140416195419.log'
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\MyTune1440_setup.exe'
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'MyTune'
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:19]i100: Detect begin, 2 packages
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:19]i000: Setting string variable 'NETFRAMEWORK40' to value '1'
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:19]i102: Detected related bundle: {1d4ce8b1-06c6-47dc-a5f7-0dba64aadd69}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.4.4.0, operation: None
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:19]i052: Condition 'NETFRAMEWORK40' evaluates to true.
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:19]i101: Detected package: NetFx40RedistCompressed, state: Present, cached: Complete
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:19]i101: Detected package: MyTune, state: Present, cached: Complete
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:19]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0EBC:0F04][2014-04-16T19:54:31]i000: Setting numeric variable 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' to value 1
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:31]i200: Plan begin, 2 packages, action: Install
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:31]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: NetFx40RedistCompressed
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:31]i201: Planned package: NetFx40RedistCompressed, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:31]i201: Planned package: MyTune, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:31]i207: Planned related bundle: {1d4ce8b1-06c6-47dc-a5f7-0dba64aadd69}, type: Upgrade, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, dependency: None
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:31]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:31]i300: Apply begin
[0F00:0C10][2014-04-16T19:54:31]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0F00:0C10][2014-04-16T19:54:33]i361: Created a system restore point.
[0F00:0C10][2014-04-16T19:54:33]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\{8c1caa8f-1ff2-4691-9e98-0af4f5fdffd8}\.be\MyTune1440_setup.exe' to: 'C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Package Cache\{8c1caa8f-1ff2-4691-9e98-0af4f5fdffd8}\MyTune1440_setup.exe'
[0F00:0C10][2014-04-16T19:54:33]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {8c1caa8f-1ff2-4691-9e98-0af4f5fdffd8}, version: 1.4.4.0
[0F00:0C10][2014-04-16T19:54:33]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {62105E4D-AAC1-4A87-95FB-BBDD34926285}, version: 1.4.4.0, package: MyTune
[0F00:0C10][2014-04-16T19:54:33]i325: Registering dependency: {8c1caa8f-1ff2-4691-9e98-0af4f5fdffd8} on package provider: {62105E4D-AAC1-4A87-95FB-BBDD34926285}, package: MyTune
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:33]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:36]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:36]i410: Variable: EulaAcceptCheckbox = 1
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:36]i410: Variable: LaunchTarget = C:\Program Files\\GearHead Software\MyTune\MyTune.exe
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:36]i410: Variable: NETFRAMEWORK40 = 1
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:36]i410: Variable: ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files\
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:36]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 4
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:36]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:36]i410: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 0
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:36]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\MyTune_20140416195419.log
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:36]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = GearHead Software, LLC
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:36]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = MyTune
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:36]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = C:\MyTune1440_setup.exe
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:36]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {8c1caa8f-1ff2-4691-9e98-0af4f5fdffd8}
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:36]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:36]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 1.4.4.0
[0EBC:0604][2014-04-16T19:54:37]i007: Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No
```

Here is the log when installing the bundle with .net included while that same bundle is already installed (this works correctly, WixBundleInstalled is set to 1):

```
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:51]i001: Burn v3.8.1128.0, Windows v5.1 (Build 2600: Service Pack 3), path: C:\MyTune1440_setup.exe, cmdline: ''
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:51]i000: Initializing string variable 'LaunchTarget' to value '[ProgramFilesFolder]\GearHead Software\MyTune\MyTune.exe'
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:51]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\MyTune_20140416195651.log'
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:51]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\MyTune1440_setup.exe'
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:51]i100: Detect begin, 2 packages
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:51]i000: Setting string variable 'NETFRAMEWORK40' to value '1'
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:51]i102: Detected related bundle: {1d4ce8b1-06c6-47dc-a5f7-0dba64aadd69}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.4.4.0, operation: None
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:51]i052: Condition 'NETFRAMEWORK40' evaluates to true.
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:51]i101: Detected package: NetFx40RedistCompressed, state: Present, cached: Complete
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:51]i101: Detected package: MyTune, state: Present, cached: Complete
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:51]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:55]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x642
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:55]i410: Variable: LaunchTarget = C:\Program Files\\GearHead Software\MyTune\MyTune.exe
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:55]i410: Variable: NETFRAMEWORK40 = 1
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:55]i410: Variable: ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files\
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:55]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 4
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:55]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 0
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:55]i410: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 1
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:55]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\MyTune_20140416195651.log
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:55]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = GearHead Software, LLC
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:55]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = MyTune
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:55]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = C:\MyTune1440_setup.exe
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:55]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {8c1caa8f-1ff2-4691-9e98-0af4f5fdffd8}
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:55]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:55]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 1.4.4.0
[0F94:0BE4][2014-04-16T19:56:55]i007: Exit code: 0x642, restarting: No
```

Answer (score 0):

Another bundle is found but it seems that no action is scheduled.
Try to add the next code:

```
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="[ProductName] is already installed." AllowDowngrades="no" Disallow="no" AllowSameVersionUpgrades="no" Schedule="afterInstallInitialize" />
```